# MongoDB $near returns duplicate records

Tags: mongodb, spatial-index

```
Event Schema:
    Name:String,
    Description: String,
    Location:[
          ll:[long,lat]
          type: String (source,destination)
    ],
    CreatedDate:Date,
    UpdatedDate:Date,
```

Example of a document:

```
 {
   Name : 'Test1',
   Description : 'Test1',
   Location:[{
         ll:[{long:-118.2436849,lat:34.0522342}],
         type: 'source'
   },{
         ll:[{long:2,lat:4}],
         type: 'destination'
   }] 
}
```

I have 7 documents having the same structure as above.

When I make a query :

```
 db.events.count({'location.ll' : {$near:[-118.2436849,34.0522342]},'location.type':'source'});
```

I get 14 count back. I should ideally get 7 records but I am getting 14 records. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have already indexed the field "location.ll" as "2d"

Please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [documented](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/) "feature", and you can get around it by following the suggestions:

> For documents with multiple coordinate values, queries may return the same document multiple times if more than one indexed coordinate pair satisfies the query constraints. Use the uniqueDocs parameter to geoNear or the $uniqueDocs operator with $geoWithin.

Comment: Thank you Felix for information. I just found the answer to my query. Thank you again. Though, I have one more question to ask: is it possible to query on a location and associated type.          db.events.findOne({'location.ll' : {$near:[2,4],$uniqueDocs:true,$maxDistance:1/3959},'location.type':'d'}). This should ideally give me no results as I am querying for all the points near [2,4] with 1 mile radius. But it gives me a result back

Comment: Not sure about `$near`, as I use `geoNear` in practice with `query` specified. Maybe you could give it a try :)

Comment: And one more note, I guess you need `$elemMatch` but that didn't work with `$near` according to [this bug report](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7581)

Comment: Thanks Felix for the help. You are amazing. I guess, I will have to redesign my schema.